# Why to capitalize some word in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Why i have to write INSERT in capital letter

```
from tkinter import *
miky = Tk()
t = Text(miky,height = 10, width = 50)
t.pack()
t.insert(END,"welcome to python programming")
miky.mainloop()
```

ok
can i make insert in small letter

in which directory tk is located and i can change it

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive. `INSERT` is a global variable defined by `tkinter`. Since it was defined as `INSERT` you must use it as `INSERT`.

> in which directory tk is located and i can change it

You can ask tkinter where it is installed by importing it and then printing out its `__file__` attribute:

```
import tkinter
print(tkinter.__file__)
```

I don't understand the question about changing `INSERT`. There's no point in changing it. If you want to use something different, just create your own variable. However, there's really no point in using constants like this. Just use a literal string (eg: `t.insert("end", "welcome to python programming")`)

Comment: Suppose i want to create my own package tkinter and how can i use it

Comment: like import. math

Comment: That's unrelated to this question and answer and can't be answered properly in a comment. If you have another question, click the "ask question" button.